# Django admin access error after deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-deployment

[image]When I try to access admin sitename.herokuapp .com/admin , then it shows this Programming Error

**Views.py file**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from . serializers import apiserializer
 from rest_framework import viewsets
 from .models import apimodel

class apiview(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = apimodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = apiserializer
```

API's fully works fine on localhost and I can POST & GET data even by django admin or via postman

**models.py file**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class apimodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**admin.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import apimodel

admin.site.register(apimodel)
```

**serializers.py file**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import apimodel

class apiserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = apimodel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'city')
```

**project/urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from apiapp import urls


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('apiapp.urls'))
]
```

**app/urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api', views.apiview)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls) )
]
```

I am unable to access django admin page after getting it deployed on herokuapp. I have already created superuser and also I have deployed by changing DEBUG=True and False, in both ways it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your models are migrated**

try

```
heroku python manage.py makemigrations
heroku python manage.py migrate
```

Note:- **heroku** is your git remote name

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. V V thankful to you. it worked for me.